# How to create an ActionLink to a custom route in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom route inside an area:

```
[RouteArea("MyArea")]  
public class MyController: Controller
{
    [Route("~/my-action")]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Before adding the **Route** and **RouteArea** attributes, I accessed this action through the following route:

```
~/MyArea/MyController/MyAction
```

Now that I added this attributes, I am able to access it just through this:

```
~/my-action
```

I used to have an ActionLink which was pointing to this action and it looked like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link To My Action", "MyAction", "My", new { Area = "MyArea" }, new { })
```

Now this ActionLink is no longer working. How can I fix  it?

Comment: You `ActionLink` would never have worked - you controller is named `MyController` so it would have need to be `@Html.ActionLink("Link To My Action", "MyAction", "My", new { Area = "MyArea" }, new { })`

Comment: Sorry, this is just an example and I did a mistake when changing the names of the Area, the Controller and the Action. In my real code this is correct and I also fixed it in my question.

Comment: You are using [Attribute Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx), have you initialized this feature in the `RouteConfig.cs` file like this: `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` in the `RegisterRoutes` method?

Comment: Yes, I have initialized it.

Comment: I had the conflict earlier when using both `Traditional Routing` and `Attribute Routing` - perhaps try to remove the `Traditional` one if you have any traces of it, and just try to go with `Attributes`?

Comment: Do you mean that I should remove the Traditional routing from the whole site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

I added a Name to the route that I created.

```
[Route("~/my-action", Name = "CustomRoute")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
```

And then I used the RouteLink helper method, instead of the ActionLink one like this:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Link To My Action", "CustomRoute")
```

So, the first parameter of the RouteLink method is the text of the link and the second one is the name of the route - the same name that you've put in the Route attribute.

Comment: For me, it was sufficient to just use @Url.RouteUrl("CustomRoute")

Comment: Adding an <a> with @Url.RouteUrl helped me mout thanks Alex